# Why is didUpdateLocation not running but my GPS coordinates are still updating?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location

I'm trying to build an app that gives GPS coordinates on regular time intervals for display on a label and for sending to a web server, but it's proving difficult.  I've managed to get it to give me accurate live GPS coordinates, but I have to press a button to get the label to refresh.

I figure the didUpdateLocation method is an ok place for this for now, but it seems to never run.  I'm testing this by including an NSLog post - when I do this with Apple's LocateMe example app it runs like it should.

Below is my method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
     theLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f
        longitude: %f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,
        locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

     NSLog(@"location manager did something!!!");
}
```

Though I'm guessing that the issue lies with something outside of the above method.  I suppose I should include my viewDidLoad method as that's where I startUpdatingLocation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [outletLabelData setText:(@"Loaded")];
}
```

I've also tried having the startUpdatingLocation in my button action method, and even having it work like a switch where you start and stop the updates (which should trigger the update event), but still no success.

Other details:

- **Xcode 4.4**
- **iOS 5.1**
- Testing app on my **iPhone while plugged into my mac**

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your `CCLocationManager` who is the delegate. In your case it is your current controller.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
```

and obviously make sure that your controller conforms to `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Awesome thanks, that was it.  Yeah the CLLocationManagerDelegate is important as well, I was going to make an edit in your answer but you beat me to it!  I'll accept your answer once it lets me.  Ah I've got a lot to learn about Xcode and iOS apps.